# How to copy a material UI style for a different pseudo class?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

My buttons are styled in a determined way because of the theme I am using, what I would like to do is force my button to look like its active state based on a react state, it is a navigation bar that is going to store which button is selected so that the button remains with the active look. How can I do that using withStyles?

Comment: Can you reproduce this situation using CodeSandbox and then ask what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: I just would like to keep the button pressed. That's it.